# Error: TransformError SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ";" (8:20)

Tags: react-native

Trying to experiment in React Native however keep having errors on my android emulator, here's the error

Error: TransformError SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ";" (8:20)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Button} from 'react-native';

import Header from './components/Header';
import Input from './components/Input';

const App = () =>{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      todoInput: '';
      todos:[
        {id: 0, title: 'sample1', done: false},
      ]
    }
  }

  function addNewLog(){
    console.log(this.state.todos);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Header title="myLogBook" />
        <Input
          textChange={todoInput => todoInput}
          addNewLog={() => this.addNewLog}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex: 1,
  }
});

export default App;
```

Comment: you are using a functional component which is state less so you can't use state here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use state in your code you can use class component like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Button} from 'react-native';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Input from './components/Input';

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      todoInput: '',
      todos:[
        {id: 0, title: 'sample1', done: false},
      ]
    }
  }

   addNewLog=() => {
    console.log(this.state.todos);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Header title="myLogBook" />
        <Input
          textChange={todoInput => todoInput}
          addNewLog={() => this.addNewLog}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex: 1,
  }
});

export default App;
```

In your code you are doing a mistake where you are using `;` instead of `,`

change `todoInput: '';` to `todoInput: '',`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank You @user12129132